# Move levelplot colorkey labels closer to colorkey

Tags: r, maps, raster, levelplot, rastervis

How can I move the `colorkey` `lables` closer to the `colorkey`? The labels for the color breaks are too far from the colorkey. I would like them very close to the colorkey. Any thoughts?

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
library(colorRamps)

set.seed(100)
ras <- raster(ncol=100, nrow=100)
ras1 <- setValues(ras, (1:ncell(ras))/100 + rnorm(ncell(ras)) - 50)

s=stack(ras1,ras1,ras1,ras1)

color_levels=14 #the number of colors to use
max_abolute_value=max(abs(c(cellStats(s, min), cellStats(s, max)))) #what is the maximum absolute value of raster?
    color_sequence=unique(round(seq(-max_abolute_value,max_abolute_value,length.out=color_levels+1),0))

myColorkey <- list(at=color_sequence,space = "bottom",tck = c(0,0), ## where the colors change 
                       labels=list(axis.line = list(col = NA),at=color_sequence,rot=0,cex=0.9,font=6,
                                   fontface=1),height=1,width=1.4)

col1 <- colorRampPalette(c("darkred", "red3","red", "gray96", 
                           "lightskyblue", "royalblue3", "darkblue"))

levelplot(s,contour=F, layout=c(4, 1),  col.regions = col1,colorkey=myColorkey,margin=FALSE,xlab=NULL,ylab=NULL,par.strip.text=list(cex=0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the distance by using `grid.edit` after calling the `levelplot` function and change the `y` parameter:

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
library(colorRamps)
library(grid)

set.seed(100)
ras <- raster(ncol=100, nrow=100)
ras1 <- setValues(ras, (1:ncell(ras))/100 + rnorm(ncell(ras)) - 50)

s=stack(ras1,ras1,ras1,ras1)

color_levels=14 #the number of colors to use
max_abolute_value=max(abs(c(cellStats(s, min), cellStats(s, max)))) #what is the maximum absolute value of raster?
color_sequence=unique(round(seq(-max_abolute_value,max_abolute_value,length.out=color_levels+1),0))

myColorkey <- list(at=color_sequence,space = "bottom",tck = c(0,0), ## where the colors change 
                   labels=list(axis.line = list(col = NA),at=color_sequence,rot=0,cex=0.9,font=6,
                               fontface=1),height=1,width=1.4)

col1 <- colorRampPalette(c("darkred", "red3","red", "gray96", 
                           "lightskyblue", "royalblue3", "darkblue"))

levelplot(s,contour=F, layout=c(4, 1),  col.regions = col1,colorkey=myColorkey,margin=FALSE,xlab=NULL,ylab=NULL,par.strip.text=list(cex=0))

grid.edit("[.]colorkey.labels$", grep=TRUE, global=TRUE, y=unit(1.5, "mm"))
```

Comment: Can you use the example included to demonstrate your solution? Thanks.

Comment: @code123: Updated my answer including your example code.

Comment: This is sweet. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that in the `layout` argument you have `4 column` and `3 rows`. Reducing the number of `rows` should fix the problem.

```
levelplot(s,contour=F, layout=c(4, 1),  col.regions = col1,colorkey=myColorkey,margin=FALSE,xlab=NULL,ylab=NULL,par.strip.text=list(cex=0))
```

Comment: @Geo-sp        I guess the question states 'Move levelplot colorkey labels closer to colorkey'. How can I reduce the distance between the values below the colorkey and the colorkey itself?

Comment: Oh, sorry about that; did you check axis.margin argument? I think this this is something @Oscar Perpiñán can answer.

Comment: @Geo-sp        Oh! Not yet. I did not know axis.margin argument exists. Hopefully Oscar can help.

Comment: Sorry but the `axis.margin`argument is only useful for the margin (by the way, it is now deprecated because the argument `margin` is a list). Unfortunately, I cannot provide any solution for your question.